# Conda is installing older version of Spades even though latest version is there in the bioconda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am trying to install [spades](https://anaconda.org/bioconda/spades) using conda. Even though the bioconda has the latest version, the version getting installed in my system is an older version 3.13. Initially, I thought creating a new environment (with python 3.8) will resolve the issue. But still, conda is installing the old version.
I am using conda version 23.1.0.
I appreciate your help in this matter.
Thank you in advance.

#post updated. Thanks, @merv

I tried both `conda install -c "bioconda/label/cf201901" spades` & `conda install -c bioconda spades`
The output will go as follows and then install the older version

```
Retrieving notices: ...working... done
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
```

Here is the output for `conda info` in the base environment.

```
active environment: base
    active env location : /tmp/yes
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /home/ubuntu/.condarc
 populated config files : /home/ubuntu/.condarc
          conda version : 23.1.0
    conda-build version : 3.23.3
         python version : 3.9.16.final.0
       virtual packages : __archspec=1=x86_64
                          __glibc=2.35=0
                          __linux=5.15.0=0
                          __unix=0=0
 base environment : /tmp/yes  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /tmp/yes/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /tmp/yes/pkgs
                          /home/ubuntu/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /tmp/yes/envs
                          /home/ubuntu/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/23.1.0 requests/2.28.1 CPython/3.9.16 Linux/5.15.0-1027-oracle ubuntu/22.04.1 glibc/2.35
                UID:GID : 1001:1001
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Comment: Works fine for me on **osx-64** and **linux-64**: yields `3.15.5`. Please add more details, like exact commands used, other packages already installed in the environment, and possibly `conda info` output.

Comment: @merv I updated the post to include the requested details. Could you please look at it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Bioconda has [very specific channel requirements](https://bioconda.github.io/#usage) because all packages are built with `conda-forge` prioritized. Hence, one must use the prioritization:

```
conda-forge > bioconda > defaults
```

So, to properly install a Bioconda package with an *ad hoc* command, one would use:

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge -c bioconda spades
```